# Unit test - Mocking Service and Repository/Unit Of Work Layer

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, repository-pattern, xunit, unit-of-work

In my current implementation I use the Domain Service layer to inject the repositories through Unit Of work.

In some cases, I inject other Services into my Service.

However, I have found difficulties to Mock these objects when making unit tests, because whenever a Service class has injection of dependencies with other Services I need to mock the dependencies of that other service.

How to make it work in a simple way?

Was I using the layers wrongly?

Eg:

```
public class ValueService : IValueService
    {
        private readonly ITestService _testService;
        private readonly IOptionService _optionService;


        public ValueService (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
            ITestService testService,
            IOptionService optionService) : base(unitOfWork)
        {
            _testService = testService;
            _optionService = optionService;
        }
```

When I'm going to mock the `ValueService` class, I need to mock the `TestService` and `OptionService` together with their dependencies.

Can you help me to think about this architecture that I'm implementing?

Comment: If you use those interfaces on top of EF or EF Core, yes, the entire design is wrong. A DbContext is already a unit-of-work, a DbSet is already a repository. There's no need for "generic" repositories.  Check [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). Using a "generic repository" on top of EF Core can easily end up executing 30 deletes for each call to `Insert`

Comment: If you mock `IValueService` you don't need to mock it's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. I hope it helps.

> You can inject all your services and repositories.

```
public class ValueServiceTest
{
   private readonly IValueService _valueService;

   public ValueServiceTest()
   {
       _valueService = GetService();
   }

   ***********************
   Your test methods.
   ***********************

   private ValueService GetService()
   {
       var services = new ServiceCollection();
       
       services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
       services.AddScoped<IValueService, ValueService>();
       services.AddScoped<ITestService, TestService>();
       services.AddScoped<IOptionService , OptionService >();
       
       **********************************
       You can inject repositories here. 
       **********************************

       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

       return serviceProvider.GetService<IValueService>();
   }

}
```